# draw bar and line charts in chart control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Chart ID="chartSellThru" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="1200px" >
    <Series>                       
        <asp:Series Name="ActualsQTD">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="ForecastQTD">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="QTDRatio" ChartType="Line">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="TargetAttain" ChartType="Line">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="SellThruChartArea">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>

chartSellThru.Series["ActualsQTD"].XValueMember = "ProductGroup";
chartSellThru.Series["ActualsQTD"].YValueMembers = "ActualsQTD";
```

I have written above lines of code in default.aspx page, and last two lines of code is written in default.aspx.cs page. Data is binding to chart.

How to write the code for line chart. Make sure values are binding from database.how to bind values from sql server to line chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think do you need two series should bind to the chart if so i'm placing the below code

In aspx page

```
  <asp:Chart ID="ChartDemo" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="1200px">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="ActualsQTD">
                    </asp:Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="ForecastQTD">
                    </asp:Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="QTDAttainMent">
                    </asp:Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="QTDRatio">
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="SellThruChartArea">
                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

and in the aspx.cs page

```
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = SrcObj.GetSellThruChartData(ddlFiscalMonth.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlReportWeek.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddlArea.SelectedValue.ToString());
        //Column Chart
        ChartDemo.Series["ActualsQTD"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        ChartDemo.Series["ActualsQTD"]["PointWidth"] = "0.9";            
        ChartDemo.Series["ActualsQTD"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";
        ChartDemo.Series["ActualsQTD"]["PixelPointDepth"] = "99";
        ChartDemo.Series["ActualsQTD"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
        ChartDemo.Series["ForecastQTD"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        ChartDemo.Series["ForecastQTD"]["PointWidth"] = "0.9";            
        ChartDemo.Series["ForecastQTD"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";
        ChartDemo.Series["ForecastQTD"]["PixelPointDepth"] = "99";
        ChartDemo.Series["ForecastQTD"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
        ChartDemo.ChartAreas["SellThruChartArea"].AxisX.Interval = 1;            
        ChartDemo.ChartAreas["SellThruChartArea"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        //ChartDemo.ChartAreas["SellThruChartArea"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

        ChartDemo.Series["ActualsQTD"].XValueMember = "ProductGroup";
        ChartDemo.Series["ActualsQTD"].YValueMembers = "ActualsQTD";            
        ChartDemo.Series["ForecastQTD"].XValueMember = "";
        ChartDemo.Series["ForecastQTD"].YValueMembers = "ForecastQTD";
        ChartDemo.Series["ActualsQTD"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;            
        ChartDemo.Series["ForecastQTD"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

        //Line Chart
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDAttainMent"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDRatio"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;           

        ChartDemo.Series["QTDAttainMent"].XValueMember = "";
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDAttainMent"].YValueMembers = "QTDAttainMent";
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDRatio"].XValueMember = "";
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDRatio"].YValueMembers = "QTDRatio";

        ChartDemo.Series["QTDAttainMent"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDRatio"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

        ChartDemo.Series["QTDAttainMent"].BorderWidth = 3;
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDAttainMent"].Color = Color.Green;
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDRatio"].BorderWidth = 3;
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDRatio"].Color = Color.Red;

        ChartDemo.Series["QTDAttainMent"].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
        ChartDemo.Series["QTDRatio"].YAxisType= AxisType.Secondary;           

        ChartDemo.DataSource = ds;
        ChartDemo.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty simple:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("OMG look a connection string"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT xValue, yValue FROM chartPoints"))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open()

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                chartSellThru.Series["QTDRatio"].Points.DataBindXY(rdr, "xValue", rdr, "yValue");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //handle errors
        }
    }
}
```

You can also set this command as a `SelectCommand` for an `SqlDataSource` and bind that to the chart, then choose the points with the `XValueMember` and `YValueMembers` in the same way as you've done it before:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="dsLinePoints" ConnectionString="OMG look a connection string" SelectCommand="SELECT xValue, yValue FROM chartPoints" />

<asp:Chart ID="chartSellThru" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="1200px" DataSourceID="dsLinePoints">
    <Series>                       
        <asp:Series Name="ActualsQTD">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="ForecastQTD">
         </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="QTDRatio" ChartType="Line">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series Name="TargetAttain" ChartType="Line">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="SellThruChartArea">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>

chartSellThru.Series["QTDRatio"].XValueMember = "xValue";
chartSellThru.Series["QTDRatio"].YValueMembers = "yValue";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as simple first then go for multiple series.

**Page Behind Code:**

```
Values[]={10,20,30,40,50}

weekworkline1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.LineChartSeries { Data = values, LineColor = "#2fd1f9", Name = "Working Hours" });
```

**Aspx Code:**

```
<asp:LineChart ID="weekworkline1" runat="server" ChartHeight="300" ChartWidth="900" ChartType="Stacked"></asp:LineChart>
```